# How to make group of User Defaults in swift?

Tags: ios, userdefaults

I want to store group of data into user defaults so that deleting that group deletes all the data in it. For example i want to store login related data in USER_DEFAULTS_LOGIN and all subscription related data in USER_DEFAULTS_SUBSCRIPTION. Now if I delete USER_DEFAULTS_LOGIN group it does not affects USER_DEFAULTS_SUBSCRIPTION group. This was possible in android preference as creation of preference requires name. I guess there should be similar solution in ios. I have heard of 'domains' and 'suits' but does not understands there purpose. Kindly help.

Comment: you can store Dictionaries, as long as they contain primitive types, String, Ints, Bools, etc..

Comment: thanks @SeanLintern88 but seems a hard to manage and last solution. I'm looking for some in build solution as its there in android.

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults API provides a way to set data for a key. In your example, you would define your keys to be `USER_DEFAULTS_LOGIN` and `USER_DEFAULTS_SUBSCRIPTION`. The data you associate with those keys can be one of several types - bool, number, string, URL, date, array, dictionary, or a bag-of-bytes (NSData).

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults for more details on types and API usage.

Comment: May be I'm not clear or you misunderstood it. USER_DEFAULTS_LOGIN and USER_DEFAULTS_SUBSCRIPTION are not my keys. these are names for group of keys. So for example in group USER_DEFAULTS_LOGIN I can store several key value pairs of different types (bool, number, string, URL, date, array, dictionary, or a bag-of-bytes (NSData). What benefit I''ll get from this is that once I delete a group of key value pairs it does not affect other groups. Is it possible in ios?